# How to smart delete all files of a folder and back-up file details on Mac?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I'm looking for a way to delete all files of the Downloads folder with a shell script or applescript that is run on a daily/weekly basis and *most* importantly backs up all of the file details, except the data itself.

Deleting the files, and scheduling the script is not a problem, I could even do it with automator. The only part I really don't know how to do is the backing up of file details. I would like to backup the list of files with their details. Ideally it would be something like creating an *alias* for every file. To save a sort of browsable back-up *without* the data, just the file details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a script:

```
cd ~/Downloads
ls - l * >> ~\backup.txt
rm -rf *`
```

Answer (score 1):

For deleting the contents of a file you could use:

```
sudo echo "" > filename.ext
```

Hopefully will this help you enough to continue.